# How to set an element to show only for a certain period of time in Wix using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, velo

There is a chatbox button in my Wix website. I want the chatbox to appear only during the days and times I written in a dataset. For example, [This is the image of the dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4uN2.png). What I am trying to do with the dataset is that the chatbox will appear every Saturday from 7p.m. to 9p.m. How can I set the chatbox to appear only during those times with Javascript Date API.

My current code is :

```js
var day;
wixData.get("ScheduleTable", "day").then((results) => {
  day = results;
})
.catch((err) => {
 let errorMSg= err;
})
 //StartTime
 var startTime;
 wixData.get("ScheduleTable", "startTime").then((results) => {
  startTime = results;
})
.catch((err) => {
 let errorMSg= err;
})
//endTime
var endTime;
 wixData.get("ScheduleTable", "endTime").then((results) => {
 endTime = results;
})
.catch((err) => {
 let errorMSg= err;
})


$w.onReady(function () {
 //TODO: write your page related code here...
 
 var startD = new Date(Date.UTC(2019,10,day,startTime)); 
var endD = new Date(Date.UTC(2019,10,day,endTime));
var today = new Date();


if(today >= startD || today <= endD) {
  $w('#wixChat1').show();
} else {
   $w('#wixChat1').hide();
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create a database for only 1 field? Just hard code the time on the page.

Hide the Wix Chat App by default using the properties panel.

```
$w.onReady(function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay(); //Saturday is 6
    var time = date.getHours(); //7 pm is 19 & 9 pm is 21
    console.log({day,time}); //console to check day and current hour
    if(day === 6 && time >= 19 && time <= 21) {
        $w("#wixChat1").show();
    }
});
```

If you are adamant on querying the database then perform a query like below.

```
//---------------------Query

import wixData from 'wix-data';

$w.onReady(function () {
    getData();
});

function getData() {
    wixData.query('ScheduleTable') //database id
    .find()
    .then( (results) => {
        let Item = results.items[0]; //this returns the first item found in the database
        let start = Item.startTime; //this HAS to be a number and in 24 hr format
        let end = Item.endTime; //same as above
        decide(start, end);
    });
}

function decide(start, end) {
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var time = date.getHours();
    if(day === 6 && time >= start && time <= end) {
        $w("#wixChat1").show();
    }
}
```